# how to refresh the gridview after a line just deleted in /yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, pjax

i can write onclick function using ajax,when actioncolumn:delete triggered，i just reload the full div part of gridview---seem to be very old style.

But how to refresh the state of the only deleted line?
can it be possibale with pjax(i try some code by google,but fails...)?

Comment: You can use the Pjax widget and after delete, call manually pjax : https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#pjax

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
$.pjax.reload({container: '#gridId'});
```

or like this

```
$.pjax({url: 'your-url', container: '#gridId'});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is also work on yii2

```
$("<id_of_GridView>").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
```

Comment: afterAjaxUpdate is only available on Yii 1